# telescoping sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, sums-of-squares

I had to use the identity $\sin^{4}(x)=\sin^{2}(x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}(2x)$ to write the sum $\sum^\infty_{k=1} 4^k \sin^{4}(\frac{\theta}{2^k})$ as a telescoping sum. However, how would I use an identity for $\sin(3x)$ to figure out a similar telescoping sum problem. I am wondering if someone would help me out with that. I believe I would not have a problem to solve a sum, but I would not be able to come up with one.

Comment: Try to solve this : $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 3^{k}\sin^{3}\frac{\theta}{3^{k}}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \overbrace{\sin(3x) = \sin (2x+x)}^\text{Get used to this sort of thing!} \\[6pt]
= {} & \sin(a+b) \\[6pt]
= {} & \sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b \\[6pt]
= {} & \sin(2x)\cos x + \cos(2x)\sin x
\end{align}
Then use the double-angle formulas for sine and cosine.

Comment: The OP seems to ask for a telescoping sum to which they could apply this.

Comment: "how would I use an identity for $\sin(3x)$ to figure out a similar telescoping sum problem."  I thought that meant he had a similar problem and didn't see how to deal with $\sin(3x)$. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you @Did. Yes, this what I meant to ask